# How i can display a pdf on android app in 2014

Tags: android, pdf

I 'm trying to display a pdf into my app ,but the method setpluginsEnabled() doesn't exists and his substitute it's deprecated what i have to do?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_pdf);
    WebView mWebView=new WebView(MostrarPDF.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=pdfpathfile");

    setContentView(mWebView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library

**[android-pdfview from JoanZapata](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview)**

**Edit** : you can search in GitHub about your problem.

**[Android+PDF in GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Java&o=desc&q=android%20pdf&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)**